# Changing the text of a label at the start and after the code in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code which will fetch some data from a `.php` file on a website and it will format the data and show it on the form. (Using visual studio)
Sometimes the fetching of data takes some time. So I want a label named `U` to be changed to "Refreshing..." during the time it fetches the data.
So I used the below code.(I am showing the relevant part)

```
private void refresh(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        U.Text = "Refreshing ...";
        string r = HttpGet("http://www.example.com/?Fetch=OK");
        U.Text = "Done";
    }
```

But this code is not changing the text to "Refreshing ..." ,it's only being changed to "Done" even if the fetching takes 1 minute.
What's happening here? How can I make it work?

Comment: You should do your fetching on a separate thread, not the UI thread. You're locking the UI thread, so you don't see changes to the label until everything in that method is finished.

Comment: @GrantWinney Better to do it asynchronously than on a separate thread...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to handle this is typically to fetch the data asynchronously:

```
private async void Refresh(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     U.Text = "Refreshing...";
     string r = await HttpGetAsync("http://www.example.com/?Fetch=OK"); // Requires an async version
     U.Text = "Done";
}
```

This requires changing your `HttpGet` method to get the data asynchronously, and return a `Task<string>` instead of `string`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your code executes and somehow, due to either low resources on machine, the application stops while loading the resources. Once done, it updates the content. You should use Threading of .NET for this, to perform different tasks using threads.

Assign each function to a different thread, UI thread must be different, resource loading must be different too.

Have a look here, [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, I have seen your answer, and +1'd it, I like that idea but since I am unaware of that method I didn't put it here.

Comment: Just mentioning it because threading is really a poor model to handle asynchronous IO

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance sir, :) I will keep your advice in my mind and will work on it to learn it asap. :)